# Variable declaration errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-calendar-api

I am making a site that uses a google calendar to search for events happening today. I have made an AJAX request using JQuery to gather some JSON data, but at a certain point my code errors.

```
var jsonwhole = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/2smi71ngo1stlvs3dskc0q0io7bhpm3m%40import.calendar.google.com/public/basic?orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true&alt=json",
        success: function(result) {
            var events = [];
            for (i = 0; i < result.feed.entry.length; i++) {
                events.push(result.feed.entry[i]);
            }
            console.log(events);
            var eventstoday = [];
            var splitdate = Date().split(" ");
            //  var googledate =  [splitdate[0], splitdate[1], parseInt(splitdate[2]) + ","];
            var googledate = ["Wed", splitdate[1], 9 + ","];
            for (i = 0; i <= events.length; i++) {
                var eventdate = events[i].summary.$t.split(" ").slice(1, 4);
                console.log(eventdate);
                console.log(googledate);
                if (eventdate == googledate) {
                    eventstoday.push(events[i]);
                }
            }
            console.log(eventstoday);
            console.log(result.feed.entry);
        }
    });
}
```

What can you make of this: [link to the page](http://raritea.com/sched). It's a blank page, but the logic is there.

Comment: Can you post some relevant code?

Comment: That's not how stackoverflow works. You can't expect people to dig through your source. Post relevant code and your error messages here if you want people to help.

Comment: Read the error logs. It clearly says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'summary' of undefined`. It is referring to here `events[i].summary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
for (i = 0; i <= events.length; i++)
```

It should be

```
for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ee6f5bjy/